# Getting error while running script to find disk space

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sh

I am running below script:-

```
#!/bin/bash
threshold="20"
i=2
result=`df -kh |grep -v “Filesystem” | awk ‘{ print $5 }’ | sed ‘s/%//g’`
for percent in $result; do
    if ((percent > threshold))
    then
        partition=`df -kh | head -$i | tail -1| awk ‘{print $1}’`
        echo “$partition at $(hostname -f) is ${percent}% full”
    fi
    let i=$i+1
done
```

But I get the following error:

```
awk: ‘{
awk: ^ invalid char '▒' in expression
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `▒'
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: What system are you running this on?  Tried it on Ubuntu 12.04, and it works fine (I copied and pasted exactly what you had above).

Comment: Did you just copy/paste this code from somewhere on the Internet? You got plenty of quotation mark instead of quotes

Comment: 1) quotes your variable expansion: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes 2) prefer `$()` for subprocess http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: @ÉdouardLopez you do realise that in editing the type of quotes used in the command, you have potentially removed the syntax error?

Comment: @TomFenech I re-edited to restore original quotation marks

Comment: Replace temporarily the first line `#!/bin/bash` by `#!/bin/bash -vx` for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 3):

What `awk` does not work?  (your script does work fine on my Ubuntu)

This line:

```
result=`df -kh |grep -v "Filesystem" | awk '{ print $5 }' | sed 's/%//g'`
```

could be changed to:

```
result=$(df -kh | awk '!/Filesystem/ {print $5+0}')
```

Avoid using old and outdated backtics if parentheses works like this:  `var=$(code...)`

---

This:

```
partition=`df -kh | head -$i | tail -1| awk '{print $1}'`
```

could be changed to:

```
partition=$(df -kh | awk -v line="$i" 'NR==line {print $1}')
```

---

This

```
let i=$i+1
```

could be change to:

```
((i++))
```

---

This would then give some like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
threshold="20"
i=2
result=$(df -kh | awk '!/Filesystem/ {print $5+0}')
for percent in $result; do
    if ((percent > threshold))
    then
        partition=$(df -kh | awk -v line="$i" 'NR==line {print $1}')
        echo "$partition at $(hostname -f) is ${percent}% full"
    fi
((i++))
done
```

Comment: +1 As well as changing the type of quotes to the correct ones, these are good suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `‘` for a single quote not `'`. Try re-encoding your file with an editor.

Answer (score 1):

You got the answer to your syntax error, now re-write the whole script as just:

```
#!/bin/bash
df -kh |
awk -v t=20 -v h="$(hostname -f)" '(NR>1)&&($5+0>t){printf "%s at %s is %s full\n",$1,h,$5}'
```

Comment: I'm still not sure why people favour the `+0` method to convert to a number. What's wrong with the unary plus, `+$5`?

Comment: The semantics of `+$5` are unclear and ambiguous and so best avoided. Try `awk 'BEGIN{print "foo" x+0}'` vs `awk 'BEGIN{print "foo" +x}'`. The former will print `foo0` as desired in this context while the latter will print `0`. Also, the unary `+` only does numeric conversion on some awks while `+0` works on all of them. Try just a simple `awk 'BEGIN{print +x}'` using `nawk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` and you'll get a NULL string output instead of `0` like you'd get from `gawk` with that construct or from any awk with `awk 'BEGIN{print x+0}'`

Comment: Personally, I would expect `"foo" +x` to produce a numerical result rather than to concatenate strings but OK, I do see your logic. By the way, I just noticed the curly double quotes in your answer, are they put there intentionally?!

Comment: No I just copy/pasted from the OPs question. I'll fix that thanks. If you're going to use `+$5` you really should use `(+$5)` to make it unambiguous but then it's lengthier than `$5+0`, still not as clear/obvious, and it still won't work in multiple awks so IMHO it's best just avoided but whatever....